# How do I configure varnish for my vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, varnish, virtualhost

I have a centos 5.x server running Apache+Drupal with 13 vhosts. These vhosts are all Top Level Domains. Munin reports heavy swapping for a few days in a month and I discovered that these are mostly anonymous users. So I thought of having varnish handle the anonymous traffic. I searched the web and found no literature on configuring VCl file file for VHOSTS. Would appreciate if someone could point me to a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish doesn't *need* to be vhost aware, whist it operates on layer 7 - it can just listen on an IP(s) and pass to the respective backend (Apache) to decide which virtualhost it needs to serve.

In terms of being able to differentiate configurations - you can use use `http.host` -

Eg.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # Don't cache www.example.com
  if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.example\.com)$") {
    return(pass);
  }
```

Otherwise, if you don't need virtualhost specific configuration - you don't need to even let Varnish know.